# View, Stored Procedure, or Table Defined Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This query executes just fine as-is. However, SQL Management Studio won't save it as a view because I define a variable.

```
DECLARE @HighestTransaction int

SET @HighestTransaction = (SELECT     MAX(CardID)
                            FROM          dbo.Transactions)

SELECT Uploads.*, Transactions.*
FROM   Uploads LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.Transactions ON dbo.Uploads.Code = dbo.Transactions.CardID
WHERE  (Uploads.Code > CASE WHEN
           @HighestTransaction IS NULL THEN -1  ELSE @HighestTransaction END)
```

I haven't really played around with stored procedures, or user defined functions a whole lot, so I'm not sure of the best way to go about doing this. Or, if there's a better way to write this, I'm open to suggestions as well.

Comment: And specify the fields you want in the select. Select * is a particularly poor coding practice and since you have a join you would be returning one field twice which is a waste of resources.

Comment: Does SELECT * present a problem if one of the tables has a few number of columns, the other is a very specific view, and all of the resulting columns will be used by the caller? Anyway, I wrote SELECT * to save space and not distract from the other stuff. The real query does expand all of the columns, because that's what VS and SQL Management Studio both do automatically when you put in SELECT *.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You can isolate the MAX into a CTE
- MAX with no GROUP BY gives one row, so you use ISNULL there

Something like...

```
WITh cHighestCard AS
(
   SELECT ISNULL(MAX(CardID), -1) AS MaxCard FROM dbo.Transactions
)
SELECT     STAUpload.*, Transactions.*
FROM         dbo.STAUpload LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Transactions ON dbo.STAUpload.Code = dbo.Transactions.CardID
WHERE     dbo.STAUpload.Code > MaxCard --edit, error spotted by martin
```

Edit: CTE not needed: it mixes sets and scalars. Oops.

```
SELECT     STAUpload.*, Transactions.*
FROM         dbo.STAUpload LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.Transactions ON dbo.STAUpload.Code = dbo.Transactions.CardID
WHERE     dbo.STAUpload.Code >
            (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(CardID), -1) AS MaxCard
                   FROM dbo.Transactions)
```

Comment: Would the CTE return -1 if there are no records at all in the TRANSACTIONS table?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: yes `CREATE TABLE OMG (Ponies int); SELECT MAX(Ponies) FROM OMG`

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Shameless plug... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552086/does-count-always-return-a-result/2552102#2552102

Comment: As the above SQL is written, I get errors about not being able to find MaxCard, even if I add cHighestCard.MaxCard to the column list of the second SELECT.

Answer (score 2):

Since you mentioned that you tried to create this as a view, that implies you might want to use the results within another query. If that is true, I'd make this a [table-valued function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165.aspx).

Comment: I can't seem to get a table-valued function to work without at least one parameter. I really don't want any at all. Can that be done, or should I just define a blank on and set the default?

Comment: It would have to be a multi statement TVF which is a black box to the optimiser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510743/why-is-udf-so-much-slower-than-subquery/510754#510754

Answer (score 0):

That is a Stored Procedure. It's easy as pie to use. Just tell the management studio you want to make a new procedure and it will even build all the basic framework syntax for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can recode it as a subquery w/COALESCE to avoid double-typing it:

```
SELECT ....
  FROM ....
 WHERE dbo.STAUpload.code > COALESCE( 
       (Select max(cardId) from dbo.transactions),-1)
```

Then it becomes a view.

Comment: This will still execute it twice. (http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/336002/unnecessarily-bad-performance-for-coalesce-subquery)

Comment: @Martin, @Ken Downs: I'd consider ISNULL then. If cardID is smallint, say, then .code may be cast to int because of COALESCE datatype handling (optimiser may treat -1 as smallint though)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a stored procedure.  Just pass your variable in and it will work as desired.

Do a quick search and review stored procedures on msdn or books online.

Answer (score 0):

This could be just one simple view, works without using CTE.  The ISNULL against the SELECT MAX in a subquery could be easier to interpret that in-lining the ISNULL into the subquery.

```
CREATE VIEW Q_SO
AS
SELECT Uploads.*, Transactions.*
FROM Uploads
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Transactions
    ON dbo.Uploads.Code = dbo.Transactions.CardID
WHERE (Uploads.Code > ISNULL((SELECT MAX(CardID) FROM dbo.Transactions),-1))
```

As a parameterless Table Valued Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION Q_FN() RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN
SELECT Uploads.*, Transactions.*
FROM Uploads
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Transactions
    ON dbo.Uploads.Code = dbo.Transactions.CardID
WHERE (Uploads.Code > ISNULL((SELECT MAX(CardID) FROM dbo.Transactions),-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just CROSS JOIN the subquery that initialises `@HighestTansaction` to your main query, like this:

```
SELECT Uploads.*, Transactions.*
FROM   Uploads LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dbo.Transactions ON dbo.Uploads.Code = dbo.Transactions.CardID CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT ISNULL(MAX(CardID),-1) FROM dbo.Transactions) m(HighestTransaction)
WHERE  (Uploads.Code > m.HighestTransaction)
```