# UDF vs Subquery Performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have tried find the monthly total sales, total sendback values for every customer for 12 months.

With other 2 subqueries then the query become use 26 subqueries for every row and SQL statement is very big.

Then I created two sub-selects for sale and sendback totals...

The result query is become shorter but execution time is bigger than 20-30 times.

1. Is this normal
2. How can I return 0 if the subquery returns NULL..

EDIT:

```
(Select sum(chh2.cha_meblag)
 from dbo.CARI_HESAP_HAREKETLERI chh2
 where chh2.cha_normal_Iade=1 and
       chh2.cha_kod=ch.cari_kod and
       (chh2.cha_tarihi>='20130101' and chh2.cha_tarihi<='20130131')
) as Ocai
```

Comment: Questions like these are impossible to answer intelligently without seeing the code.  For your first question, though, it doesn't surprise me that a query with a UDF would be slower than an equivalent query without one.

Comment: I think to post code for 1. but i saw some question like this when googled it and just want to get a simple answer.

for the second one. 

(Select sum(chh2.cha_meblag) from dbo.CARI_HESAP_HAREKETLERI chh2 where chh2.cha_normal_Iade=1 and chh2.cha_kod=ch.cari_kod and (chh2.cha_tarihi>='20130101' and chh2.cha_tarihi<='20130131')) as Ocai,

How can set this query for return 0 when null.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your second question is to wrap the subquery in a `coalesce()`:

```
coalesce((Select sum(chh2.cha_meblag)
          from dbo.CARI_HESAP_HAREKETLERI chh2
          where chh2.cha_normal_Iade=1 and
                chh2.cha_kod=ch.cari_kod and
                (chh2.cha_tarihi>='20130101' and chh2.cha_tarihi<='20130131')
         ), '') as Ocai
```

As Martin points out in his comment, `coalesce()` has what I consider to be a bug in SQL Server.  In this case, it will execute the first expression twice, once to check the value against `NULL` and the second time to get the value.  Given this, `ISNULL()` is better (even though I prefer standard functions in general):

```
isnull((Select sum(chh2.cha_meblag)
          from dbo.CARI_HESAP_HAREKETLERI chh2
          where chh2.cha_normal_Iade=1 and
                chh2.cha_kod=ch.cari_kod and
                (chh2.cha_tarihi>='20130101' and chh2.cha_tarihi<='20130131')
         ), '') as Ocai
```

Comment: [`ISNULL is better`](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/336002/unnecessarily-bad-performance-for-coalesce-subquery)

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . Thank you for reminding me about that shortcoming in SQL Server.  Are there any plans to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your subquery it appears you could resolve your issue without correlated subqueries, and only using joins. However with only a portion of a query to work with it is difficult to be sure. This is why when posting questions it is a good idea to post as much relevant code as possible. Nonetheless, from what I gather you have somthing like this:

```
SELECT  (   SELECT  SUM(chh2.cha_meblag)
            FROM    dbo.CARI_HESAP_HAREKETLERI chh2
            WHERE   chh2.cha_normal_Iade = 1 
            AND     chh2.cha_kod = ch.cari_kod
            AND     chh2.cha_tarihi >= '20130101' 
            AND     chh2.cha_tarihi <= '20130131'
        ) AS Ocai,
        (   SELECT  SUM(chh2.cha_meblag)
            FROM    dbo.CARI_HESAP_HAREKETLERI chh2
            WHERE   chh2.cha_normal_Iade = 1 
            AND     chh2.cha_kod = ch.cari_kod
            AND     chh2.cha_tarihi >= '20130201' 
            AND     chh2.cha_tarihi <= '20130228'
        ) AS Ocai,
        ... etc for 12 months
FROM    SomeTable ch
```

You could turn this into:

```
SELECT  ch.cari_kod,
        [20130101] = ISNULL([20130101], 0),
        [20130201] = ISNULL([20130201], 0),
        [20130301] = ISNULL([20130301], 0),
        [20130401] = ISNULL([20130401], 0),
        [20130501] = ISNULL([20130501], 0),
        [20130601] = ISNULL([20130601], 0),
        [20130701] = ISNULL([20130701], 0),
        [20130801] = ISNULL([20130801], 0),
        [20130901] = ISNULL([20130901], 0),
        [20131001] = ISNULL([20131001], 0),
        [20131101] = ISNULL([20131101], 0),
        [20131201] = ISNULL([20131201], 0)
FROM    SomeTable
        LEFT JOIN
        (   SELECT  chh2.cha_kod,
                    [20130101] = SUM(CASE WHEN chh2.cha_tarihi >= '20130101' AND chh2.cha_tarihi < '20130201' THEN chh2.cha_meblag ELSE 0 END),
                    [20130201] = SUM(CASE WHEN chh2.cha_tarihi >= '20130201' AND chh2.cha_tarihi < '20130301' THEN chh2.cha_meblag ELSE 0 END),
                    [20130301] = SUM(CASE WHEN chh2.cha_tarihi >= '20130301' AND chh2.cha_tarihi < '20130401' THEN chh2.cha_meblag ELSE 0 END),
                    [20130401] = SUM(CASE WHEN chh2.cha_tarihi >= '20130401' AND chh2.cha_tarihi < '20130501' THEN chh2.cha_meblag ELSE 0 END),
                    [20130501] = SUM(CASE WHEN chh2.cha_tarihi >= '20130501' AND chh2.cha_tarihi < '20130601' THEN chh2.cha_meblag ELSE 0 END),
                    [20130601] = SUM(CASE WHEN chh2.cha_tarihi >= '20130601' AND chh2.cha_tarihi < '20130701' THEN chh2.cha_meblag ELSE 0 END),
                    [20130701] = SUM(CASE WHEN chh2.cha_tarihi >= '20130701' AND chh2.cha_tarihi < '20130801' THEN chh2.cha_meblag ELSE 0 END),
                    [20130801] = SUM(CASE WHEN chh2.cha_tarihi >= '20130801' AND chh2.cha_tarihi < '20130901' THEN chh2.cha_meblag ELSE 0 END),
                    [20130901] = SUM(CASE WHEN chh2.cha_tarihi >= '20130901' AND chh2.cha_tarihi < '20131001' THEN chh2.cha_meblag ELSE 0 END),
                    [20131001] = SUM(CASE WHEN chh2.cha_tarihi >= '20131001' AND chh2.cha_tarihi < '20131101' THEN chh2.cha_meblag ELSE 0 END),
                    [20131101] = SUM(CASE WHEN chh2.cha_tarihi >= '20131101' AND chh2.cha_tarihi < '20131201' THEN chh2.cha_meblag ELSE 0 END),
                    [20131201] = SUM(CASE WHEN chh2.cha_tarihi >= '20131201' AND chh2.cha_tarihi < '20140101' THEN chh2.cha_meblag ELSE 0 END)
            FROM    dbo.CARI_HESAP_HAREKETLERI chh2
            WHERE   chh2.cha_normal_Iade = 1 
            GROUP BY chh2.cha_kod
        ) chh2
            ON chh2.cha_kod = ch.cari_kod;
```

This may not even require a subquery, however as I have said, without your full query I can only speculate on your table structure, and the results you actually want.

To answer 1 yes it is normal for a UDF to perform worse than a subquery doing the same thing. There are a number of posts on the subject [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/510754/1048425) was top of google when I searched for [SQL-Server UDF versus subquery](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=SQL-Server+UDF+versus+subquery)