# Difference Between Scalar Function and SubQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function, view, subquery

I am experiencing a problem in View. I can't show you the exact `View` here since it will be against the Policy of Development Team.

**Below is the format of View :**

```
Create View View_Name as
Select A,B,C,D,E,F
  from  (
    Select  T.A,T.B,T.C,T.D,
        dbo.Function_1(T1.A,T2.B) E,
        dbo.Function_2(T1.A,T2.B) F,
        dbo.Function_3(T1.A,T2.B) G,
      from  (
        Select  T1.A,T1.B,T2.C,T2.D
          from  Table1 T1 
          join  Table2 T2
            on  Some_Condition_1
             .
             .
             .
         where  Some_Where_Clause
         group  by T1.A,T1.B,T2.C,T2.D
        ) T
     where  Some_Where_Condition_ForThis_InnerQuery
    ) T_Out
 where Some_Where_Conditions_For_OuterQuery
```

This View takes 5 Mins to execute.
There are 40,000 records in each table.

But, When I replaced `functions` with their respective `Queries` then Execution is very Fast. It takes hardly 2 seconds to execute.

```
I don't want to re-format my View, but I wanted to know why the execution time is 
different in both cases?
```

Comment: That would depend highly on the contents of functions themselves. But what is probably happening is that this way, functions are run for each row (40000 times). While when queries are put in their place, optimizer can find a better plan and do the calculations while reading from T1,T2

Comment: Read http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/08/04/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that SQL server can't optimize function calls it has to call it for each row. For a subquery optimizer can do its work.

There are a lot of discussions:

[Why is a UDF so much slower than a subquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510743/why-is-a-udf-so-much-slower-than-a-subquery)

[Performance, User Defined Function or Sub Query](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/229f4fa8-0dc7-4583-8cf0-ef977713634d/performance-user-defined-function-or-sub-query)