# T-SQL Get Values from Lookup table and use in view / stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I couldn't find that via search, so I guess I am not asking it the right way, so help is welcome.

We have a lookup table:

```
Id   Name
------------------
1    "Test"
2    "New"
3    "InProgress"
```

Table2:

```
StatusId  SomethingElse
  1   
  2
```

Table 1

```
ID  Other Other StatusId (Fkey to Table2) ...
```

Then we have a view that selects from several tables and one of the columns is a CASE Statement:

```
    SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 -- has million records

    CASE When t1.StatusId = 1 THEN (SELECT Name from LOOKUP table where ID = 1) END --'Test'
    CASE When t1.StatusId = 2 THEN (SELECT Name from LOOKUP table where ID = 2) END --'New'
CASE When t3.Date is not null THEN (SELECT Name from LOOKUP table where ID = 3) END --'In Progress'
-- AND ALSO the case look at other tables another 5-6 tables and there are conditions from there
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on ...
INNER JOIN Table3 t3 on ...
```

As you see these are really static values.

I want to load them once into variables, e.g.

```
 @LookUp1 = SELECT [NAME] FROM LookUP WHERE Id = 1, 
 @LookUp2 = SELECT [NAME] FROM LookUP WHERE Id = 2
```

and replace the select in the CASE statement to this:

```
When StatusId = 1 THEN @LookUp
When StatusId = 2 THEN @LookUp2
```

The view loops through millions of records and it gets really slow to do the select from Lookup table for every row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply use a join?

```
SELECT <columns list from main table>, Lt.Name
FROM <main table> As Mt -- Do not use such aliases in real code!
JOIN <SecondaryTable> As St -- this represents your Table3
    ON <condition> 
[LEFT] JOIN <Lookup table> As Lt
    ON Mt.StatusId = Lt.Id
    OR (Lt.Id = 3 AND St.Date is not null)
```

Of course, replace `<columns list from main table>` with the actual columns list, `<main table>` with the name of the main table and so on.

The join might be an inner or left join, depending on the nullability of the `StatusId` column in the main table and if it's nullable, on what you want to get in such cases (either a row with null name or no row at all).

I've put together a little demonstration to show you exactly what I mean.

Create and populate sample tables (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE LookUp (Id int, Name varchar(10));

INSERT INTO LookUp (Id, Name) VALUES
(1, 'Test'), (2, 'New'), (3, 'InProgress');


CREATE TABLE Table1 (Id int not null, StatusId int null);

INSERT INTO Table1(Id, StatusId)
SELECT n, CASE WHEN n % 3 = 0 THEN NULL ELSE (n % 3) END
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 30 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID) As n
    FROM sys.objects
) tally

CREATE TABLE Table3
(
    Id int not null,
    Date date null
)
INSERT INTO Table3 (Id, Date) 
SELECT Id,  CASE WHEN StatusId IS NULL AND Id % 4 = 0 THEN GetDate() END
FROM Table1
```

The query:

```
SELECT  Table1.Id, 
        Table1.StatusId, 
        Table3.Date,
        LookUp.Name
FROM Table1
JOIN Table3
    ON Table1.Id = Table3.Id
LEFT JOIN LookUp 
    ON Table1.StatusId = LookUp.Id
    OR (LookUp.Id = 3 AND Table3.Date IS NOT NULL)
```

Results:

```
Id  StatusId    Date            Name
1   1           NULL            Test
2   2           NULL            New
3   NULL        NULL            NULL
4   1           NULL            Test
5   2           NULL            New
6   NULL        NULL            NULL
7   1           NULL            Test
8   2           NULL            New
9   NULL        NULL            NULL
10  1           NULL            Test
11  2           NULL            New
12  NULL        27.06.2019      InProgress
13  1           NULL            Test
14  2           NULL            New
15  NULL        NULL            NULL
16  1           NULL            Test
17  2           NULL            New
18  NULL        NULL            NULL
19  1           NULL            Test
20  2           NULL            New
21  NULL        NULL            NULL
22  1           NULL            Test
23  2           NULL            New
24  NULL        27.06.2019      InProgress
25  1           NULL            Test
26  2           NULL            New
27  NULL        NULL            NULL
28  1           NULL            Test
29  2           NULL            New
30  NULL        NULL            NULL
```

You can also see a live demo on [rextester.](https://rextester.com/OFPP33225)

Comment: Because it is in a CASE statement and it depends on other values/rows of thew view

Comment: For the scenario you've shown in the question, the join I proposed is a better alternative. If your actual scenario is different in such a way you can't implement the solution using a `join` instead of a `case`, then the code example in the question is not good enough and you should edit the question with a code example that can actually demonstrate the problem accurately.

Comment: May be the example is not good, or may be I don't understand how to apply the JOIN. I will edit the question a bit. Please have a look in a minute

Comment: I have edited - Can the JOIN be applied in my case and how?

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: I don't see how to use join, when I have criteria from several tables in the CASE statement

Comment: I've edited my answer. Basically, you just need to get a little creative with the `on` condition.

Comment: ha, that's great, I didn't know about conditions on JOINS

Answer (score 0):

Create a SQL function which return Name according to Id.

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[GetLookUpValue] 
(
@Id int
)
RETURNS varchar(500)
AS BEGIN
    return(Select Name from LOOKUP_table with(nolock) where Id=@Id)
END
```

Comment: Yeah, but that will again be executed million times (for every row in the view). That is what I don't want.

Comment: or left join your view with LOOKUP table and get the name

Comment: This is a bad idea. Scalar functions are known as performance killers

Comment: @ZoharPeled yeah, functions are performance killers, but here he is not asking for speed.

Comment: the OP might not be asking for speed, but the question does mention millions of rows in the main table. You are suggesting to run a known performance killer on every single one of these rows. Do you really think it's not a bad idea?

Comment: function is just equivalent to subquery

Comment: Yes, it is equivalent and that is what I am showing (subquery) as bad performing in my current code. Any help is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: then just use left join with case statement in joining condition

Comment: @Ravi It's not equivalent. It's much, much worst. See [Why is a UDF so much slower than a subquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510743/why-is-a-udf-so-much-slower-than-a-subquery) for details.

Comment: Hm, I had heard that functions are very slow, but didn't know they were that bad...thanks everyone!